# What are the best markup conversion libraries for Python 3?

Tags: open-source, software-development, python, markdown

**I am not asking just for recommendations, I am asking for a detailed explanation of *why* your recommendations are the best over other libraries.**

My use case is in a forum. No other details should be needed, but feel free to ask.

**I need the following text formattings to be supported:**

- *italic*
- **bold**
- `unformatted code`
- [links](https://www.google.com)
- ### large headers

**Optional, but requested:**

- lists

  - numbered
  - bulletted
- strikethrough
- underline
- > block quote
- `formatted code`
- embedded images

**I need (what you think are) the best Python 3 compatible modules (preferably via `pip`) specifically to convert the following markup languages to HTML:**

- BBCode
- Markdown
- ReStructuredText

HTML, of course, is a given.

No need to convert them back. I do however need to be able to disable specific formatting (like headers in comments) if need be.

If there are any other markup languages you think belong on a forum editor, let me know.

These modules should be lightweight, and not too difficult to install. They must also be open source compatible.

Comment: Please edit your question to match the site rules: i.e.: Should not be a "Best" as this leads to a debate. It should be "Python 3 Mark-up library with the following features".

Comment: @Steve Barnes My question does not violate the "no debate rules" because I am not asking for a discussion of the topic. I am asking for them to simply state their opinion, as they would do regardless of the question title. I simply added that they should specify *why* their recommendations are "best" for my needs to rule out answers with a list of links. It is a prompt for a small summary of each of their recommendations.